# Go logger to print timestamp

Tags: go

Go logger to print timestamp

I have the following:

```
l := log.New(os.Stdout, "[AAA] ", 2)
l.Printf("Listening on %s", addr)
```

This prints out `[AAA] Listening on ~`

Is there any way that I can configure `log` package to print out

`2014-09-15 10:23:12 [AAA] Listening on ...`

?

Comment: You should consider using [glog](https://github.com/golang/glog), a pretty full featured log pkg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get your *specific requested output*, you can wrap it in your own `Log` function and set the prefix each time using `SetPrefix` (or embed a logger in your own type and extend it with another function):

```
func Log(l *log.Logger, msg string) {
    l.SetPrefix(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") + " [AAA] ")
    l.Print(msg)
}
```

For example:

```
l := log.New(os.Stdout, "", 0)

Log(l, "Log 1")

<-time.After(time.Second * 3)

Log(l, "Log 2")
```

..outputs this on my machine:

```
2014-10-02 11:12:14 [AAA] Log 1
2014-10-02 11:12:17 [AAA] Log 2
```

Note that the `log` package has [some predefined flags](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants) that you can use, however they don't produce the format you've requested in your question. To get it exactly like that, you have to pass zero for the flags and do it yourself.

Comment: This `Log` function will acquire and release the loggers mutex twice. It might be more efficient to simply print the desired prefix.

Comment: So it does! I was unaware that it acquired a lock for setting the prefix. Thanks @Volker

Comment: For high-throughput, low-latency logging, this solution doesn't seem very performant. Have a look at this example here https://play.golang.org/p/Sup-mCZe9k and run it on your local box. On my MacBook I observe a 1 to 3 millisecond lag in log writes on average, which for many applications is unacceptable. The `SetPrefix()` method appears very expensive.

Comment: @nmurthy Sure, Volker mentions its quite slow in the comments above yours. This does directly answer the OPs question though.. so I'm not sure why you've decided to downvote. The OP doesn't explicitly state high perf logging is a requirement and has accepted the answer. I'm not sure downvoting is required if the answer _doesn't help you_ ... its more whether it helps the OP in the context of their original question, which it has... given its accepted.

Answer (score 7):

```
l := log.New(os.Stdout, "[AAA] ", 2)
l.Printf("Listening on %s", addr)
```

Prints out `[AAA] 17:07:51 Listening on ...`

If you want to add the date, use `log.Ldate | log.Ltime` as flag:

```
l := log.New(os.Stdout, "[AAA] ", log.Ldate | log.Ltime)
l.Printf("Listening on %s", addr)
// [AAA] 2016-07-14 17:07:51 Listening on ...
```

But for having the date and time before prefix, you can use a customized writer:

```
type writer struct {
    io.Writer
    timeFormat string
}

func (w writer) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return w.Writer.Write(append([]byte(time.Now().Format(w.timeFormat)), b...))
}
```

Then, pass the custom writer to log's `New`:

```
l := log.New(&writer{os.Stdout, "2006-01-02 15:04:05 "}, "[AAA] ", 0)

l.Printf("Listening on %s", addr)
// 2016-07-14 17:07:51 [AAA] Listening on ...
```

**There is a complete example [here](https://gist.github.com/farshidtz/a64cb850e0a0c544823628ca4bc0e995).**

Answer (score 4):

set go log flag [log flags](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants):

```
log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags)
```

Comment: adds a date, but _after_ the prefix, not before.

Comment: Its `log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags) or log.SetFlags(3)`
And `log.Print("Hello world")` as `2022/02/02 19:36:00 Hello world`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure when it was added but you can also just set the `Lmsgprefix` flag

```
Lmsgprefix   // move the "prefix" from the beginning of the line to before the message
```

e.g.:

```
log.SetFlags(log.Lmsgprefix | log.LstdFlags)
```

Comment: This is the most accurate answer.
`
func logger(whichController string) *log.Logger {
 return log.New(os.Stderr, whichController, log.Lmsgprefix|log.LstdFlags)
}

headerReq := r.Header.Get("X-Request-ID")
log := logger(fmt.Sprintf("[post: /logins req id %s] ", headerReq))

`
will produce messages like 
`2023/07/22 19:05:11 [post: /logins req id 123] loginUseCase.Execute - starting login use case`